# GoLang log URL without query parameter value

Tags: http, go, logging

I am implementing Datadog tracing and I would like to record the URL route from which the logs was recorded. However, I want to log the URL without the query parameter value.

For example,

Given that the URL is `/user/{user_id}/profile` with `user_id` as a query parameter, I want to log the string `/user/{user_id}/profile` instead of `/user/11/profile` where 11 is the user id.

I've tried the following but I was not able to achieve what I want

- r.URLPath,
- r.URL

where r is of type `*http.Request`

Is there any way I could achieve and log the route without the query parameter value and only the placeholder?

Comment: That's not a query parameter but it's just part of the URL's path. The variable part (user_id) means just as much as the `/user` and `/profile` parts in there, and you will need some way to let whatever library you're using for your Datadog integration know what the normalized route pattern is. I suggest adding the library you're using to your question to get a better answer

Comment: could you please post the code that shows the tracing implementation of your HTTP router. I could help you but I need some code to understand how you could achieve that